# Wrong urls generated by ASP.NET MVC in staging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I've encountered strange behavior an can't find what is going on, hope somebody will give an idea.
So there is simple and standard route map:

```
 routes.MapRoute("Category",
         "category/{categoryName}/{id}",
          new {
                controller = MVC.PublicProduct.Name, 
                action = MVC.PublicProduct.ActionNames.Index, 
                id = 1
              });
```

thing is, that instead of generating this:

```
http://staging/category/sunglasses/14
```

it gives:

```
http://staging/?action=index&controller=publicproduct&id=14&categoryname=sunglasses
```

strange things are:
1) if I enter right url into address bar, it works
**2) it behaves so only in staging, on local machine (also IIS7) and production, it works as supposed, so I guess it is some kind of IIS setting.**

UPDATE:
One of samples how url's are generated:

```
<a href="@Url.Action(MVC.Basket.Index())">My Cart</a>
```

Comment: I've had this issue where Ajax caused this to happen every time I try to redirect from it.

Comment: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/497/user-friendly-url---rule-template/

Comment: Do you have the default route: `{controller}/{action}/{id}`? If, yes then this explains your problem: the two routes are incompatible and the routing engine cannot disambiguate between them so it picks the first one in the list.

Comment: It should be not Ajax problem, it should work without url rewrite module, I have default route, but that does not explain why it works on local machine :)

Comment: Could you post the code you use to actually generate the item that generates the URL (ActionLink, etc)?

Comment: I've updated question with item that generates url, but thing is that in two environments it generates right urls, and only in single one produces wrong ones, so I don't think issue is in MVC code, I think it is IIS configuration issue (also there's several sites running on faulting IIS, in all urls work fine except this one, so it should be single IIS site scope problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting site from IIS and disk and creating fresh one solved the problem, luckily this was staging, so no one was harmed.